# Ubuntu 16.04 Server Permission denied(publickey,password). via ssh connection

Tags: 16.04, openssh

Can I not connect ssh connection my server ,i searched all question and tried, but not working.

I  re-establish the openssh-server, change sshd_config file and change my root password.

PermitRootLogin no -> PermitRootLogin yes

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are trying to exchange keys but can't log in to do so?  I recommend using 'ssh -v' or even 'ssh -v -v -v' to get more information about what is failing.

Setting

```
PermitRootLogin yes
```

in /etc/ssh/sshd_config should do it.  And don't forget to restart the ssh server:

```
sudo service ssh restart
```

Comment: I tried the solution above but it did not ssh -v output:
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password

Comment: Try 'ssh -v -v -v' for even more information and post that.

Comment: I threw it this way because it was too long
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1tsRBLU6mLzpwJ6Heh82WEyWYAON3CbFa5nFTFUGTwPg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you log in with a  password in the end?  I don't see a failure in the log.  Also note: it would be better to login in to a user account once with password to do a ssh-copy-id to set up keys.  Then use ssh to the user account followed by sudo.  If you really want to login as root, you should set up keys.

Comment: root@kemal:~# ssh-copy-id root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: ERROR: failed to open ID file '/root/.pub': No such file
 (to install the contents of '/root/.pub' anyway, look at the -f option)

Comment: Oh, that means that root on the local machine does not have ssh keys.  So obviously, you would need to make ssh keys first using ssh-keygen.  But seriously, please consider doing the ssh as a normal user and then using sudo.  Root logins are  a potential security hole.

Comment: I have /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub file but not opening.

Comment: kemal@kemal:~$ ssh  -i /ssh/id_rsa.pub root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
Warning: Identity file /ssh/id_rsa.pub not accessible: No such file or directory.
The authenticity of host 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:------------------------------------.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx's password: 
Permission denied, please try again.
root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx's password:

Comment: Looks to me like you have the wrong path and the `-i` flag should specify the private key or identity file.  Anyway,  you should not need to specify that explicitly.  E.g. do: `ssh root@host`.  You should only need `-i` if you have multiple identities.